# How to remove multiple roles from all members in a guild discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm attempting to have self-assigned roles that users can get in order to have access to specific voice/text channels and I want to be able to remove said roles from all who have it with a single command (so for when I work on adding more features to said roles, I can ensure no one really interferes).

Currently, I'm working with this so far, it's meant to remove all self-assigned roles from the person who typed out the command, for now I've made it only for admins, but it ain't really working hahaha.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def swipe(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role1 = get(member.guild.roles, name = "Minecraft")
    role2 = get(member.guild.roles, name = "CS:GO")
    role3 = get(member.guild.roles, name = "Valorant")
    role4 = get(member.guild.roles, name = "PUBG")
    role5 = get(member.guild.roles, name = "TF2")
    role6 = get(member.guild.roles, name = "COD")
    await member.remove_roles(role1, role2, role3, role4, role5, role6)
    await ctx.send(f'Removed **all** experimental roles.')
```

So to sum it up, I'm trying to create a command that allows admins to be able to remove certain roles (Minecraft, CS:GO, Valorant, PUBG, TF2, COD) from everyone in the server who has said role with a single command (swipe). All suggestions and ideas are welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `get()` is being imported from `discord.utils`, this would remove all specified roles from the user that executes the commmand:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def swipe(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role_names = ("Minecraft", "CS:GO", "Valorant", "PUBG", "TF2", "COD")
    roles = tuple(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=n) for n in role_names)
    await member.remove_roles(*roles)
    await ctx.send(f'Removed **all** experimental roles.')
```

And this would remove all specified roles from all members in the server that have it:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def swipe(ctx):
    role_names = ("Minecraft", "CS:GO", "Valorant", "PUBG", "TF2", "COD")
    roles = tuple(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=n) for n in role_names)
    for m in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.remove_roles(*roles)
        except:
            print(f"Couldn't remove roles from {m}")
    await ctx.send(f'Removed **all** experimental roles.')
```

The `try`/`except` is there for the users that the bot won't be able to remove the roles from. This is most like because the bot doesn't have enough permissions to do it or one of the roles is higher up than the bot's highest role in the role hierarchy.

---

**References:**

- [`*args` usage](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558)
- [`Member.remove_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

Comment: Hey, I tried integrating this into the code, but all it does is reply with Couldn't remove roles from user#id so for example: Couldn't remove roles from Diamond#2195. It doesn't remove the roles. For reference, the bot is in the highest role in the server, and the roles it is removing are at the bottom. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Diamond Sorry for the late reply! Hm, that's odd.. Would you mind replying with, or editing your answer with the full traceback for that error?

Comment: Yep! So whenever I do run the command, this is printed in my terminal:

Couldn't remove roles from USER#7132
Couldn't remove roles from USER#0064
Couldn't remove roles from USER#9419
Couldn't remove roles from USER#4503
Couldn't remove roles from USER#5238
Couldn't remove roles from USER#3164
Couldn't remove roles from USER#9056

And so on and so forth for all members in the server. Instead of USER, it says their actual discord username, I just changed it in this showing to preserve their identity. 

It seems like it's just going straight to raising the expectation.

Comment: @Diamond The bot won't be able to remove roles that are above its highest role in the server's role list - make sure that it has the `Manage roles` or `Administrator` permission, and drag that role above all of the ones that it tries to remove. In the same way we wouldn't be able to, as users, remove someone's role if it was higher than ours in the hierarchy.

Comment: As previously stated, I did that. The bot is currently in the highest role in the server, with every other role being under it. I assigned it all the needed permissions. Still no luck, unfortunately. I also tried this in another server wherein the only roles that exist are the bot's and the roles in the tuple. Still no luck.

Comment: @Diamond If you remove the `try`/`except` and just keep the `remove_roles(*roles)` line, what error is given? Is it a role that's not being found maybe?

Comment: Hey, I tried removing try/expect. My terminal didn't print anything when I ran it. Also, it now does not send the last line (await ctx.send), although it's outside of the for bracket.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch the m for member, it fixed this problem for me

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def swipe(ctx):
    role_names = ("Minecraft", "CS:GO", "Valorant", "PUBG", "TF2", "COD")
    roles = tuple(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=n) for n in role_names)
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.remove_roles(*roles)
        except:
            print(f"Couldn't remove roles from {member}")
    await ctx.send(f'Removed **all** experimental roles.')
```